# Is it possible to use the SANE backend on windows platforms?

Tags: windows, sane

I have to develop a scanning application for the Canon 9000F, but I'm having troubles with WIA and TWAIN. I've read on the SANE project's home page that this specific scanner works pretty well with their technology, so I would be interested if it is possible to use the SANE backend on Windows platforms.

I found some information on this website: http://www.zago.net/sane/windows/sane_on_windows.html

> SANE on Windows:
>   The port has been integrated in the CVS tree on september 23rd, 2003.
>   It will be available in SANE release 1.0.13.

Windows is also listed as platform on the SANE's wikipedia page:

> Operating system: Microsoft Windows, Linux, UNIX, OS/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spite of this very interesting thread: [sane runs in windows without cygwin](http://sane.10972.n7.nabble.com/sane-runs-in-windows-without-cygwin-td13328.html) I think that your only really viable option for using SANE on Windows is to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) with [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).  From the [README.windows](https://github.com/rudimeier/sane-backends/blob/master/README.windows) file:

> SANE on Windows
>
> ## Prerequisites
>
> To be able to compile sane-backends, you need to have either Cygwin or
>   Mingw compilers and a suitable POSIX compatible environment.
>
> You can get the Cygwin POSIX compatible environment for Windows
>   Windows and the Cygwin gcc compiler at http://www.cygwin.com
>
> You can get the MSYS POSIX compatible environment for Windows and the
>   MinGW gcc compiler at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS
>
> The scanner must be detected by Windows and not be disabled. Check
>   with the hardware manager.

Once you have either of those, you can untar and build SANE from the source code (check the readme for the required libraries) and it may or may not work with your `Canon 9000F` Scanner.

As you say, the chances are good that it will work as it is listed as supported under the [pixma](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html) backend.

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part was handled by TWAIN which is no longer an option as Windows moves forward.  The SANE backends need to be built under Cygwin.  Won't build with Mingw - no POSIX functionality.